# GDB alias for shell command

Tags: shell, gdb

When I use gdb, I want to rebuild the program by run shell script (for example "./scripts/build.sh"), so I assigned alias by the command :

```
alias build = 'shell ./scripts/build.sh'
```

but error occurred

```
Invalid command to alias to: shell ./scripts/build.sh
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alias` defines a new command that is an alias of an existing command. `shell  ./scripts/build.sh` is *not* and existing command.

Do this instead:

```
(gdb) define build
> shell ./scripts/build.sh
> end
```